# I am found in mountains and sands, I bring joy and pain, what am I?

Tags: riddle, knowledge, wordplay

I am found in many lands, from the mountains to the sands. I bring you joy and sometimes pain, and can make you play again. What am I?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE! If you are interested in learning more about this site (and earning another badge while you're at it), check out the Help Center: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help

Answer (score 2):

A long shot:

> Shell

I am found in many lands, from the mountains to the sands.

> Shells are notoriously distributed not only to the shores but also to mountains due to how earth progressed. Ross can provide further info.

I bring you joy

> They are used in decoration, and also in a romantic "listen the sea of sound in them" fashion

and sometimes pain

> a shotgun shell, an artillery shell can do that

and can make you play again

> Well until now, the "knowledge" tag is not used. Since "play" is intrisically linked with "game", I'm sure anyone can think of some game with some shell in it. Any FPS with shotguns will do. I opt for Shelly de Killer from the Ace Attorney series.

Comment: This was my guess the moment I read it. Lol

Comment: ebg13(V guvax "Znxr lbh cynl ntnva" vf va ersrerapr gb gur "Furyy Tnzr" ubj vg vf nqqvpgvir gb xrrc cynlvat naq jva zbarl ba gur fgerrg.)

Answer (score 2):

I think it is:

> Life
>  Life is found almost everywhere. It is found on mountains and in the sand.
>  Life brings both joy and pain to us.
>  and with an extra life I can play again.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE! Great work on your first answer! If you are interested in learning more about this site (and earn a badge while you're at it), check out the Help Center: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is

> Salt
>  Salt brings joy as a common seasoning with a savory quality.
>  Pain could mean someone who is **salty**. Eating salt by itself is also painful, lol. Even food that is too salty is no good.
>  Salt can make you play again because it is a common source of the electrolyte sodium(think Gatorade etc.) - electrolytes aid in effective hydration.